# Handler not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, onsubmit

see the following code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validate()
            {
                fname = f.fn.value;
                if(fname!= "abc")
                    alert("Incorrect name!")

                lname = f.ln.value;
                if(lname != "xyz")
                    alert("Incorrect Name!")

                paswd = f.pswd.value;
                if(paswd<8)
                    alert("Too short password!")

                for(var i=0; i<f.d.length; i++)
                {
                    if(f.d[i].value.checked)
                    {
                        document.write(f.d[i].value);
                    }   
                }

                for(var i=0; i<f.c.length; i++)
                {
                    if(f.c[i].value.checked)
                    {
                        alert(f.c[i].value);
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="f" onsubmit="validate()">
            First Name: <input type = "text" name = "fn"> <br>
            Last Name: <input type = "text" name = "ln"> <br>
            Password: <input type = "password" name = "pswd"> <br>
            E-mail: <input type = "email" name = "mail"> <br>
            Degree : <input type = "radio" name = "d" value = 's'> SE 
            <input type = "radio" name = "d" value = 'c'>CS 
            <input type = "radio" name = "d" value = 'E'>IT <br>
            University
            <select name = "uni">
                <option value = 'p'>PU</option>
                <option value = 'f'>FAST</option> 
            </select> <br>
            CGPA : <input type = "radio" name = "c" value = '3'> >=3.0
            <input type = "radio" name = "c" value = '2'> >=2.5 <br>
            Browse <input type = "file" name = "uf">  <br>
            <input type = "Submit" value = "Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i press the submit button,I should get a message of

> Incorrect name

or

> too short password

if the conditions are true but nothing happens, why?
Why the

> validate()

function not running?

Comment: You have the <form>-tag twice.

Comment: Open up the browser console, and check if there are any errors when you click submit. Alternately, put an `alert("hello");` just to see if it makes it into that function

Comment: it doesn't get inside the function, i've tried putting an alert("hello"); statement there

Comment: If the function is not executed then it's (a) either in the wrong scope or (b) doesn't exist because the parser cannot parse it (syntax error).

Comment: You shouldn't *change* your original code. Now all the answer who addressed the `int` problem don't make sense anymore. If you really hadn't `int` there, then it's ok of course. But if you had it, changed it, and it still doesn't work, add additional info to your question. But don't change the original question.

Comment: ok @ Felix Kling.(changed that beacause the discussion was going in the wrong direction and answers were wrong too, just got lucky that i don't have 125 reputation)

Comment: But now the code you posted seems to do what you want (it shows the alerts): http://jsfiddle.net/6xpGM/2. So what's the problem?

Comment: no it doesn't.... that's the problem

Comment: Yes it does. Did you see my demo? Click the button and you see the alert. If it doesn't for you, then you are not using the code you posted. We cannot help you if we are unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: well it's showing alert at the link above but not working with my google chrome...

Comment: Then you are **not** using the code you posted here and we cannot help you without for information from your side. Sorry. I mean seriously, how do you expect us to find a problem in some code we know nothing about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Problem

```
int i
```

makes no sense.  This *would* be proper **Java** syntax, but not in **Javascript.**  I think you mean `var i`

### What else?

You have two form tags.

### PS

If you're too lazy to open your web browser's console (or if it doesn't have one), just use the `try` and `catch` expressions.

### I'm too lazy to fix all these issues.  Just give me the fixed code

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6xpGM/1/)**

Comment: f.fn.value is getting value from the form "f" and text field "fn",it's not undefined

Comment: And why is `int i` a problem?

Comment: *"If you're too lazy to open your web browser's console (or if it doesn't have one), just use the try and catch expressions."* That wouldn't really help in this case and there is no need to be snide.

Comment: @FelixKling It's not proper javascript syntax

Comment: Maybe you should explain this in your answer.

Comment: *"[...] `var i` still won't work, because you're duplicating a variable."* Uh? It's perfectly fine to have multiple `var X` statements for the same variable.

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

Just use form once:

```
<form> // <--- remove this line
<form name="f" onsubmit="validate()">
```

Second, you're using a mixture of what seems like JAVA and JavaScript, so instead of for(int i, declare your variable with var. Like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < f.d.length; i++) { <--- var instead of int
    if (f.d[i].value.checked) {
        alert(f.d[i].value);
    }
}
```

That should remove all the errors, you could have also seen these errors yourself when using the correct debugging tools. Here is a list of them:

- Chrome DevTools: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console
- Firebug: http://getfirebug.com/
- For Internet Explorer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255006(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Couple of error in your code

```
 <html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
  fname = document.f.fn.value;
  if(fname!= "abc")
  alert("Incorrect name!");

  lname = f.ln.value;
  if(lname != "xyz");
  alert("Incorrect Name!");
  paswd = f.pswd.value;
  if(paswd<8)
  alert("Too short password!")
   for(i=0; i<f.d.length; i++)
    {
    if(f.d[i].value.checked)
    {
        document.write(f.d[i].value);
    }   
     }
    for(i=0; i<f.c.length; i++)
     {
    if(f.c[i].value.checked)
    {
        alert(f.c[i].value);
    }
      }
   // return false;  // use this you don't want to submit form
   // return true;  //for advancing the form
   }
 </script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="" name="f" onsubmit=" return validate()">
First Name: <input type = "text" name = "fn"> <br>
Last Name: <input type = "text" name = "ln"> <br>
Password: <input type = "password" name = "pswd"> <br>
E-mail: <input type = "email" name = "mail"> <br>
Degree : <input type = "radio" name = "d" value = 's'> SE 
<input type = "radio" name = "d" value = 'c'>CS 
<input type = "radio" name = "d" value = 'E'>IT <br>
University <select name = "uni">
<option value = 'p'>PU</option>
<option value = 'f'>FAST</option> 
</select> <br>
CGPA : <input type = "radio" name = "c" value = '3'> >=3.0
<input type = "radio" name = "c" value = '2'> >=2.5 <br>
Browse <input type = "file" name = "uf">  <br>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

above code is working

I consider that you are performing validation on this form hence you need to the call the function

```
return validate();
```

Now if function return false, the form is not submitted

if function return true, the form is submitted

Do ask for further help , Don't waste my effort's

Comment: sanjeev,i didn't understand your answer